# How to calculate the time extends with rest time

Tags: vba, excel

Given that a start time and end time .

Like 8:30- 10:30 , so I can calculate the duration (minutes) -->120

the situation : every 45 min , a short 5 mins break will be given .

It will be 8:30-9:15 (first session) (45min accumulate ) ,9:15-9:20(1 rest time) ,9:20-10:05(2 session)(90 min accumulate ) ,10:05-10:10 (2 rest time) .10:10-10:40 (3 session ) (reminding time 30 min =120-90) , no third rest

**i just want to output : 8:30 -10:40(start to end) & every rest time(start and end ) : 9:15 to 9:20 , 10:10-10:40**

Any excel or VBA solutions to perform this ?

the sample input can be : 830-12:34 ,930-1732 , 9:30-23:67

My current working :(total minute as 158)
8:30-11:08
first calculate the duration in minute

[image]

**Input :830 , 11:08**

**output : red line in picture : new end time , every rest time start ,every rest time end**

Comment: hi vito - not sure what you are asking exactly. you want 45 minute increments outputted based a start time and end time, and to include a 5 minute break?

Comment: yes , so it will extend the originally end time .The 5 minute break would not be included in the originally total duration

Comment: Please explain the yellow high-lighted 158 minutes in your example. Please post a picture of the result you want, given a start time of 8:30 and end time of 10:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The code below calculates every time in the process. To test it, take a blank worksheet, enter a start time in B2 and an end time in C2, then run the code. Install the code in a standard code module. A standard code module will have the default name of `Module1`. It is none of the modules available in a new workbook. You will have to add it. (Right-click on the VBA project in the Project Explorer window on the left of your VBE screen and select `Insert` and `Module`.)

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                                ' worksheet navigation
    ' 15 Jan 2018
    NwsFirstResultRow = 4
    NwsCaption = 1                      ' 1 = column A
    NwsStart                            ' each period's start time
    NwsEnd                              ' 3 = C
End Enum

Sub CalculateRestTimes()
    ' 15 Jan 2018

    Const StartTime As String = "B2"    ' change as required
    Const EndTime As String = "C2"      ' change as required
    Const BreakTime As Long = 5
    Const WorkPeriod As Long = 45

    Dim Tstart As Double, Tend As Double
    Dim Twork As Double, Tbreak As Double
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long
    Dim p As Integer

    Twork = Round(WorkPeriod / 1440, 6)
    Tbreak = Round(BreakTime / 1440, 6)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("RestTimes")        ' change as required
        Tstart = Round(Val(.Range(StartTime).Value2), 6)
        Tend = Round(Val(.Range(EndTime).Value2), 6)
        If Tstart = 0 Or Tend = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Start or end time is not entered correctly.", _
                   vbCritical, "Invalid or missing entry"
        End If

        R = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsCaption).End(xlUp).Row, NwsFirstResultRow)
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(NwsFirstResultRow, NwsCaption), .Cells(R, NwsEnd))
        Rng.ClearContents
        R = NwsFirstResultRow - 1

        Do While Tstart < Tend
            R = R + 1
            p = p + 1
            .Cells(R, NwsCaption).Value = Ordinal(p) & " period"
            .Cells(R, NwsStart).Value2 = Tstart
            Tstart = Application.Min((Tstart + Twork), Tend)
            .Cells(R, NwsEnd).Value2 = Tstart
            If (Tstart + (20 / 1440)) <= Tend Then
                R = R + 1
                .Cells(R, NwsCaption).Value = Ordinal(p) & " rest"
                .Cells(R, NwsStart).Value2 = Tstart
                Tend = Tend + Tbreak
                Tstart = Tstart + Tbreak
                .Cells(R, NwsEnd).Value2 = Tstart
            Else
                .Cells(R, NwsEnd).Value2 = Tend
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(NwsFirstResultRow, NwsStart), .Cells(R, NwsEnd))
        Rng.NumberFormat = "HH:mm"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function Ordinal(ByVal n As Integer) As String
    ' 13 Jan 2018

    Dim Suff As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Suff = Array("th", "st", "nd", "rd")
    i = n Mod 10
    Ordinal = CStr(n) & Suff(IIf(i > 3, 0, i))
End Function
```

Comment: what is the time in column C?

Comment: Can I add one more criteria ,bro ? I hope last period is at least >25 minutes . If <25 minute , no need add 1 more period .

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but the way I do understand you are pointing at something my code didn't do the way I wanted. I have modified it. Please take a look. Column C is the projected end time after each step. It can be removed if useless. I think we have all the numbers now, tell me how you want them arranged.

Comment: Like last rest time 13:00-13:05 , the last period will be 13:05-13:15 .(<20 min ) If the last period duration <20 min , 10 min(13:15 minus 13:05)  will be added to last two period  , and the original last rest time will be cancelled .

Comment: OK. I added one line of code: `If (Tstart + (25 / 1440)) >= Tend Then Tstart = Tend`

Comment: I change from 25 to 20 . As I want to set the limit to 20 minutes .I find the total minute will be incorrect with  the change . Any problem ?

Comment: I found that the last period cannot add up the remaining minute (the reminder of /45min)

Comment: Can't replicate your error. I tried Start = 8:30, End = 12:34. The macro calculates the final end time as 12:54 which equals to the original end time of 12:34 plus 4 rest periods. Looks correct to me. Which start and end did you use for your test?

Comment: i tried to add `If (Tstart + (20 / 1440)) >= Tend Then Tstart = Tend` Column C is correct .However , the last number in Column B is 12:35 <--incorrect

Comment: Please noted that I change the code variable from 25/1440 to 20/1440

Comment: I understand your program now .the 5th period start time will be (last number in column B :12:35) .The 5th period end time will be last number in column C .I have a suggestion .Is it possible to make 12:54 to be last number in column B and named it as new end time .It would be perfect .

Comment: The new version of my code gives you two columns, start and end time of each period - work and rest. This removes a logical flaw on my previous attempt. I believe that you only want one of the columns. Does one of those now available fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

The following user-defined functions will be calculated excluding breaks.

```
Function getTime(s, e)
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim myTime As Date, t As Date
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim Other()

    Set wf = WorksheetFunction
    If s > e Then
        myTime = e - s + 1
        s = 0
    Else
        myTime = e - s
    End If
    t = s + TimeSerial(0, 45, 0)
    Do
        n = n + 2
        ReDim Preserve Other(1 To n)
        Other(n - 1) = t
        Other(n) = t + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
        t = t + TimeSerial(0, 50, 0)
    Loop While e > t
    With wf
        For i = LBound(Other) To UBound(Other) Step 2
            If Other(i + 1) > e Then Exit For
            myTime = myTime - (.Min(e, Other(i + 1)) - .Max(s, Other(i)))
        Next i
    End With
    getTime = myTime * 1440
End Function
```

[image]

Break time will come to the table.

```
Sub test()
 Dim s, e

 s = Range("b9")
 e = Range("B27")

 getTimetable s, e, Range("b10")

End Sub
Sub getTimetable(s, e, target As Range)
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim myTime As Date, t As Date
    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim Other()

    Set wf = WorksheetFunction
    If s > e Then
        myTime = e - s + 1
        s = 0
    Else
        myTime = e - s
    End If
    t = s + TimeSerial(0, 45, 0)
    Do
        n = n + 2
        ReDim Preserve Other(1 To n)
        Other(n - 1) = t
        Other(n) = t + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0)
        t = t + TimeSerial(0, 50, 0)
    Loop While e > t
    With wf
        For i = LBound(Other) To UBound(Other) Step 2
            If Other(i + 1) > e Then Exit For
            myTime = myTime - (.Min(e, Other(i + 1)) - .Max(s, Other(i)))
        Next i
    End With
    If n Then
        target.Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Other)
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: see edit , I need the  output : red line in picture : new end time , every rest time start ,every rest time end

Comment: for the Sub test(), supposedly ,I don't know the new end time .

Comment: I have a old start and end time ,8:30-11:08. I will calculate the new start and end time (8:30-11:23 ) and every start rest time and end rest time .

Comment: I don't know your  start and end time's cells. It is Only you know.

Comment: Yes , I mean I have a old start and end time to calculate the new end time .But your screen cap seems to use to new end time to calculate every rest time . Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Is'nt your end time  cell b27?

Comment: Yes , I will enter the old end time .However , with the 5 min breaks added , the end time will be changed . <-- the new end time should be longer .(the 5 min breaks will not be counted within the total time )

Answer (score -1):

Please try this formula, where the start time is in B2 and the end time is in C2. The formula will return a new end time extended by 5 minutes for every 45 minut4es of original work time.

```
=$C2+(INT(($C2+IF($B2>$C2,1,0)-$B2)*1440/45)*5/1440)
```

I think the formula should return a wrong result if there are 9 or more breaks within the net work time. If this is really so and if that is an issue it can be adjusted.

Comment: That isn't the way I understood the requirement.

Comment: @pnuts. Thank you for your concern. I went by the OP's comment under his original question. Let's wait what he says.

Comment: I need the start and new end time ,as well as the every rest time ,rest time will be a bit difficult (because you don't know how many rest time session ,and rest time will not be included as the total time  ) ,thanks bro